# How to reorder certain pandas columns without dropping the other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

i have 9 columns that i'm trying to reorder, while keeping all the others. i'm sure this has been asked before, but i'm not sure if i'm using the correct search terminology.

essentially if my data columns looks like:

```
Case  A   C  D  B  E  F  H  G  Name
```

i want to resort into:

```
Case A  B  C  D  E  F G  H Name
```

without having to specify each individual column like:

```
df = df['Case','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','Name]
```

because the actual data has 120 or so columns.

Comment: You would have to provide some logic based on which you want to reorder the columns. In the above example, I would probably do df.columns = ['Case'] + list(string.ascii_uppercase) + ['Name']. For df with 120 columns, you haven't provided the logic

Comment: i would want hypothetical columns A-H to follow the order of a prespecified list

Comment: how complex is your sort? if its basic a list sort will do, if its more complex, as you already have pandas initalised, you could cast your columns to a series, sort them then cast them back.

Comment: not very complex. basically i have ten variables that i want to sort based upon a list i've specified, while keeping all the other variables. reindexing by that list drops all the other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted`:

```
new_columns = ['Case'] + sorted(df.columns[1:-1]) + ['Name']

df = df[new_columns]
```

Output:

```
Case    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   Name
```